# Grails redirect action index

Tags: grails, redirect, indexing

So i have this controller with a reset(erasing some data ), index and other methods, so at the end of the reset method i have a redirect to the index method.
What is the difference between :

```
redirect(action: "index", id: params.id)

redirect(action: index, id: params.id)
```

The first one works perfectly , redirects me in the index method but the second one redirects me on a different method.(`getEndMonthsList` which is the last method in the controlller)

Comment: Version of grails : Grails 2.0.0

Answer (score 2):

The two variants that you showed were valid before Grails 2 because only closures could be used to define actions. So you could redirect either to 'index' or `index` because you were referring to the closure property with the second approach, and Grails would build the full URL from its name. It is slightly slower so it was always better to use the String approach though.

In 2.0 things changed and methods are allowed to be used as actions, and are the preferred approach. So if you have an `index` method, it's no longer a public field in the class that you can refer to like any other variable, it's a method that isn't directly referenceable by name. So the string approach is the only one that works.

I tried to use the non-string approach to reproduce this but it didn't fail the way you described, it failed with a missing property exception when the index action was defined as a method (as expected) and worked fine when it was defined as a closure (again, as expected).

Answer (score 0):

In first case Grails invokes controller method by name.
In second case Grails gets closure name and invokes controller method by name.

See `org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.metaclass.RedirectDynamicMethod#establishActionName`